# Adding IBOutlet - XCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to add a `scrollview` for my `view`  I am going to my `AppDelegate.h` file and adding the following:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;

    IBOutlet  UIScrollView  *mainScroll;

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;


@end
```

Than I go to my `IB(storyboard)` and right click on my `scrollview` to try and add the outlet but I don't see the created IB?

David

Comment: why in the AppDelegate??? Create a view controller and put it in there

Comment: @alecnash what do you mean?

Comment: David just start by reading an iOS book or tutorial or just watch the iTunesU videos for creating an app cause you just need to learn some more things before you start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here you go:
This video just outlines the process of creating a project and linking a scroll view. The part where you see a blue line form, it is because I a holding down control.

Here is the link to the video (it is mp4 so you might have to download it)

http://cl.ly/113D3j0Y2z04

Comment: Why do you keep adding new answers instead of editing your original answer?

Comment: too late now though, sorry

Comment: No, you can edit the first one and delete the others.

Comment: i just deleted the other overall bc they didnt really help

Comment: @Askask so I looked at waht you did, why would that not work with using an empty project?

Comment: An empty project does not automatically create the view controller files and link them with the storyboard; that is another very annoying process that is very easily averted by creating it as a single view application

Comment: well you should be able to just copy and paste it over, what other work have you done so far?

Comment: as in images? because images can simply be dragged in. If you already had content int he storyboard you may have to recreate that unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

> Than I go to my IB(storyboard) and right click on my scrollview to try and add the outlet but I don't see the created IB?

The app delegate isn't included in a storyboard file, so you won't be able to connect the scroll view to an outlet in the app delegate. You probably shouldn't need to do that anyway -- normally it'd make more sense for a view controller to manage its own views than to have the app delegate manage something in the view controller's view hierarchy.

So, short answer: consider moving the outlet to whatever view controller manages this scroll view.

Comment: I have my view controller but where do I go to edit it's source code? I don't see a file for it.

Comment: Create a subclass of `UIViewController`. It sounds like you haven't, and you're just using a plain old `UIViewController` instance. If you do, you can change the type of the view controller in the storyboard to your subclass.

Comment: Ohh that is probably why, could you give me a hand doing that?  Than I would have a File's owner cube correct?

Comment: No, File's Owner is something you see in .xib files but not storyboards.

Comment: Whats the difference from .xib and the storyboard (in a view sense)

Comment: A storyboard typically contains several different view controllers and their respective view hierarchies, and you transition from one to the next with segues. .xib files generally each contain a single view controller and it's view hierarchy, but can contain any collection of objects. To use the objects in a .xib you have to load that .xib file (there are a couple ways you can do that), and in order for the objects in the .xib to be properly connected to the rest of the app you have to specify an object that owns them, and this object is represented by the "File's Owner" proxy icon.

Comment: Okay...so if I want to edit my view control file directly how would I access it?

Comment: [Here's a page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/WritingaCustomClass.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH18-SW1) that explains how to create a subclass. You might want to [start at the beginning of the tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH2-SW1), though, as there's a lot of good info in there.